# Good way of dividing a list of lists in two parts, conditional to the values in the inner list

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, destructuring, short-circuiting

The objective is to start with the following:

```
budget = 100
projects = [('B', 60), ('A', 35), ('F', 35), ('G', 35), ('C', 20), ('E', 20), ('D', 10)]
```

And achieve `projects=[('B', 60), ('A', 35)]` and `remainingBudget =5`.

As a JS programmer, I have gotten the following to work by some means:

```
def findProjectsThatFitTheBudget(budget, projects):
    # find the most expensive projects that fit the given budget, and note the budget that remains after allocations
    remainingBudget = budget

    def shoulIncludeProject(name, cost):
        nonlocal remainingBudget
        if(cost <= remainingBudget):
            remainingBudget -= cost
            return True
        return False
    projects = list(
        takewhile(lambda project: shoulIncludeProject(project[0], project[1]), projects))

    # we now have the projects we are working with, and also the budget that remains unallocated
```

I wonder what is the most pythonic way of refactoring this? I was stuck with the following at the least:

1. How do I write a simple lambda instead of an external def
2. How do I do destructuring in the arguments to the lambda
3. How do I use `and` in a short-circuit way with `budget=-cost`

A beautiful solution could have been:

```
projects = list(
    takewhile(lambda name, cost: cost<= budget and budget=-cost, projects))
```

using `and` in the `short-circuit` way.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with a simple `for` loop that short-circuits when budget is depleted:

```
viable_projects = []
for project, cost in projects:
    budget -= cost
    if budget < 0:
        break
    viable_projects.append((project, cost))
```

`viable_projects` becomes:

```
[('B', 60), ('A', 35)]
```

Comment: thanks. still quite verbose for Python :) will leave the question open for a short while